# How does one send SSIS log provider messages to a variable

Tags: c#, ssis, 7zip

I have a SSIS package that fetches data from CSV files and retrieves them into tables. I have enabled logging throughout the package for errors and failure to a file. After the process is complete I zip all the files in the working folder (This includes the text file that I use for logging.) But during the zip process, I always encounter a file in use error. I believe this is not strange because the file is actually in use by the log provider. Is there a way to zip the file along with all the others?
Or like I proposed in my Title, is there a log provider that can send these errors to a variable and then write them to a file and afterwards zip it. This way I am sure the file is not is use when I am executing the zip task. I am using 7-zip for my zip task process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since logging is enabled on the task , the file is being lock by the provider. 
Why not , leave the file from being zipped? See the example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/185135/7zip-add-to-archive-how-to-exclude-certain-file-types-extensions) on how to exclude a file type from command line with 7zip.

Comment: Even though this helped, I believe I have found a better solution. Obviously, you cannot log into a file the you are trying to zip at the same time. So I have disabled logging on the zip file and rather decided to send a notification email when the zip task fails.